# Timer as a background job

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I want to implement a timer so as to keep track of a test program.
The timer will be in a different file and linked with my test.cc (test program).

I wantto keep track of execution, so as which statement takes how much time, and when the timer reaches certain interval may br 10 secs, i wish to do something, like may be aborting the test program.

I am using C++ in Linux environment.
Can someone tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: Also, what have you done yet and where are you stuck ?

Comment: I work is altogether different. What i gave you is a small part of the whole problem. I am in a leakcheck tool, and the thing is i want to collect leak info for a certain period, may be 10 secs to 15 secs of total execution time. I am not abl to figure out how to achieve this, no progress is made yet.

Comment: @Delan: Let me accept some of the previous answers, which (if) i find suitable.

Comment: Are you trying to *profile*?  Or do you just want to take some action after some period of time?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions possible.
If you can use POSIX threads and if the timer is only needed to end your application, then the "timer" can wait in a separate thread by using the [nanosleep](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) call.  On wakeup, a [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) can be sent (or a [signal to a thread](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unix.com%2Fman-page%2FLinux%2F3%2Fpthread_kill%2F&ei=NIBmTfKMHoPJhAe177XdDQ&usg=AFQjCNHuteYM1-fnsbFU0LTskrDe-1Lr9A)).

Comment: But suppose if the program is executing, how to switch back to the timer, periodically?